# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xe8) how to solve this

Tags: xcode, exc-bad-access

the game keep crashing in the device and xcode show me this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwpd9.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had to downgrade buildbox and everything worked perfectly.